# Using pseudo-array $@ for dynamic commands results in errors if the command includes globs

Tags: unix, scripting, zsh

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

old_IFS="$IFS"
IFS='|'

files_to_exclude="$*"

IFS="$old_IFS"

set -- -f --
set -- "$@" ./^("${files_to_exclude}")

rm "$@"
```

and I expect the following command to be executed (if the script was invoked with arguments `test.txt`, `cover.jpg` and `01.\ Filename.flac`):

`rm -f -- ./^(test.txt|cover.jpg|01.\ Filename.flac)`

Instead, when executing the script I get the following error on line 11:
`number expected`.

I presume that the reason for it is the glob character `^` which refuses to be parsed somehow. I have used [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable) resource to write the script.

I have also tried `eval` but to no avail either.

Is there a way to get this working?

P.S. I have just tried doing this using `zsh`'s function alias and it is not working either:

```
rm-excluding() {
    rm -f -- ./^($*)
}
```

Invoking the above with `rm-excluding a b` results in:

`rm-excluding:1: bad pattern: ./^(a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here; you're not explaining the *what*, you're focusing on a rather convoluted *how* instead. It looks like you're trying to build up a glob pattern that's supposed to expand to all but a list of files known at runtime.

One way, using `zsh`'s more advanced [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) features to first join the positional parameters together with `|` characters while building the pattern, and then to force filename expansion on it (Which can also be enabled globally with the `GLOB_SUBST` option I prefer to do it case-by-case):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# Just in case it's turned off somehow by your setup
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB

# Build the pattern by joining position parameters with pipes
excluded="^(${(j:|:)argv})"

# And expand with zsh's ${~spec} form of parameter expansion
# to force the expanded value to undergo filename expansion
print -l -- ${~excluded} # Replace with rm when you're sure it's working right
```

Note the use of a variable named `argv`; it's an array version of the positional parameters that can be used instead of `$*` or `$@` in `zsh` that often ends up being simpler to work with.

You could also avoid a complicated glob completely by using array difference expansion (`:|`):

```bash
# Make an array with all matching files and remove the ones in $argv
typeset -a allfiles=(*)
print -l -- ${allfiles:|argv}
```

which is the option I'd prefer; it's simpler with fewer moving parts for unexpected behavior.

Comment: Fair assesment - upon re-reading my question it's clear what should've been asked vs what was asked. I'm glad you managed to figure out what I was after in the end. I ended up using the array difference expansion and it worked a treat. Succint, easy to understand and clearly a better approach than what I was trying to do in the script, thanks